# Rails 4 - How to get collective count of models associated with models within a category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my rails app `users` have `groups`, which have different contact forms models called `contactables`, which `contact` records belong to.

Here the model classes...

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :forms
  has_many :popups
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
    has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end

class Popup < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
    has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I can easily count the number of contacts a form has by going form.contacts.count

I'm trying to get the count of the contacts within a user's `group` of contactables, like `group.contactables.contact`. That doesn't work.

How would I get the collective count of the contacts within a group of contactables, when contacts are associated through the contactables within the group?

Comment: show the model associations.. Your sentences are over killed.

Comment: Added the model classes

Comment: what do you mean by _I'm trying to get the count of the contacts within a user's group of contactables,_?

Comment: Let's say a user has a `group`. The group has 2 contactables, 1 being a  `form`, and the other being a `popup`. The form has a 4 contacts associated with it. The popup has 6 contacts associated with it. That would mean the group has a total of 10 contacts. How would I get a collective count of the contacts within a group of contactables like that?

Comment: Well... Nice explanation. I got you now.. Let me think.

Comment: Well. Can you give me the SQL query from the console of `group.forms.joins(:contacts)` ? Just give me the SQL and also what is DB client you are using ?

Comment: `group.forms.joins(:contacts).count` works! I could add that up with each contactable to return a total sum for the group, but to reduce the calls to the database, how could I do that with forms and popups in one line?

Comment: I know.. that will work.. I want to see the SQL, if I can make it a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I can solve your problem using 2 queries like :

```
form_contacts = group.forms.joins(:contacts).count
# and
popups_contacts = group.popups.joins(:contacts).count
#then add this 2 counts
form_contacts + popups_contacts # gives desired counts
```

Comment: That does it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
Contact.where(id: group.contactables.select(:contact_id)).count
```